# Cron Plugin in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, cron, cron-task

I'm trying to do a Cron Plugin for Wordpress and I don't know why it doesn't work. I have my website in Flywheel server and I don't have access to the wp-config.php file.

My code is:

```
/*
Plugin Name: CronPlugin
Description: 
Version: 1.0
Author: Anonymous
License: GPL2
License URI: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
*/

// Activación del Plugin
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'dcms_plugin_activation' );
function dcms_plugin_activation() {
    if( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'dcms_my_cron_hook' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( current_time( 'timestamp' ), '5seconds', 'dcms_my_cron_hook' );
    }
}


// Desactivación del Plugin
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'dcms_plugin_desactivation' );
function dcms_plugin_desactivation() {
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'dcms_my_cron_hook' );
}

// Acción personalizada
add_action( 'dcms_my_cron_hook', 'dcms_my_process' );

function dcms_my_process() {
    //error_log('Mi evento se ejecutó: '.Date("h:i:sa"));
    $recepients="anonymous@anonymous.es";
    $subject="Hello from your Cron Job";
    $message="This is a test mail sent by WordPress automatically as per Your schedule.";
    //let’s send it
    wp_mail($recepients,$subject,$message);
}

add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'dcms_my_custom_schedule');
function dcms_my_custom_schedule( $schedules ) {
     $schedules['5seconds'] = array(
        'interval' => 5,
        'display' =>'5 segundos'
     );
     return $schedules;
}
```

I have my Plugin activated, and also the WP-CONTROL plugin which show all cron events in a tab. When I activate my Plugin the cron event is added to the list but it doesn't send me the mail.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks !

Comment: You will need to deactivate and activate the plugin every-time you make a change to your file.

Comment: I did it, but still not working...

Answer (score 0):

You can access your config file by connection Via FTP.

https://getflywheel.com/wordpress-support/how-do-i-access-my-site-via-sftp/

Comment: Yes I have acces via FTP but Flywheel don't allow me to modify the wp-config.php. I wrote them and they put the following code in my wp-config file

define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);

But with this, it sitll not working. I don't know why...